# Why are my Angular Material buttons and links being underlined/outlined?

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, angular-material2

I am experiencing some strange outlining after clicking a button that uses any of the variations of `mat-button` from Angular Material as well as link tags being underlined when I hover the mouse over them.

[Button oulining after the button is clicked.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/26wcl.png)

[Link underlining when mouse hovering.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aa9YM.png)

I'm using Angular 6, Angular Material and also a little of Bootstrap 4. The code for the images above is simply this:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <h1>Hello</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <button mat-raised-button>Click me!</button>
        <a mat-button>Click me too!</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While posting the question, I found out that the problem was Bootstrap, but I decided to post the question either way as a way to document this behavior.

In order to fix this, either remove Bootstrap or follow what is described [here](https://www.amadousall.com/the-good-parts-of-bootstrap-4-you-are-missing-in-your-angular-material-projects/). The solution is described when the author of the post creates two Sass partials `_variables.scss` and  `_reset.scss`.

There is also another good guide on using Bootstrap and Angular Material [here](https://medium.com/@tomastrajan/how-to-build-responsive-layouts-with-bootstrap-4-and-angular-6-cfbb108d797b).

Comment: The Angular template in Visual Studio adds bootstrap by default.  This led me to locating the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue while using Angular 14 with Bootstrap (and without Angular Material). The simple solution to that was to include the `text-decoration-none` class inside the anchor tag which worked for me:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
  <a class="text-white text-decoration-none">
    Send Message
  </a>
</button>
```